# Expectation of a distribution

Tags: probability

Let $X$ follows binomial(100,0.25). How can I calculate $E(2^X)$?
That is I want to find the expected value of $2^X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $p$ for $0.25$ and $n$ for $100$. Then 
$$E(2^X)=\sum_0^n 2^k\Pr(X=k).$$
Thus 
$$E(2^X)=\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$
We can rewrite the above sum as 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (2p)^k (1-p)^{n-k}.\tag{1}$$
Recalling the Binomial Theorem $(s+t)^n=\sum \binom{n}{k}s^kt^{n-k}$, we find that our sum (1) is $(2p+(1-p))^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the probability (or moment) generating function of the binomial distribution, which is a power of the generating function of a Bernoulli distribution.